# Как создавать переменные с помощью цикла, если не знаешь заранее сколько их нужно будет их создать

Tags: python, python-3.6

К примеру нам дана задача на координатной плоскости, с прямоугольниками.

Сначала пользователь вводит количество прямоугольников которые должны быть на координатной плоскости *(обозначим эту переменную как `n`)*, затем пользователь вводит координаты этих прямоугольников *(обозначим их как  x1y1  x2y2 x3y3 x4y4, то есть по 2 переменной на каждый угол, что бы образовать точки)*, но так как мы заранее не знаем сколько прямоугольников захочет вывести пользователь, мы не знаем сколько нужно будет создать переменных соответствующих координатам углов прямоугольников.

Пожалуйста помогите, надеюсь я понятно изъяснился и вы меня поняли, если же нет, я могу попробовать объяснить еще раз.

Comment: Срочно читать про списки, массивы, словари и всё такое прочее!

Comment: Если бы вы привели пример кода, я был бы очень признателен.

Comment: Откройте же учебник, там  этих примеров предостаточно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример, как это сделать:

```
coordinates = []
print("Когда вы задали все координаты, просто нажмите на клавиш Enter.")
print()

while True:
    x = input("Координата x: ")
    y = input("Координата y: ")
    if x and y:
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        coordinates.append((x, y))
        print()
    else:
        break

print() 
print(coordinates)
print("Количество вводимых пунктов:", len(coordinates))
```

Пример работы программы:

> ```
> Когда вы задали все координаты, просто нажмите на клавиш Enter.
>
> Координата x: 1
> Координата y: 2
>
> Координата x: 7
> Координата y: 5
>
> Координата x: -1
> Координата y: 3
>
> Координата x: 
> Координата y: 
>
> [(1, 2), (7, 5), (-1, 3)]
> Количество вводимых пунктов: 3
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

`coordinates` сначала пустым *списком* (`[]`). К списку можно добавлять элемент по элементу методом `.append(элемент)`. Мы добавляли пары - это в Питоне *кортеж* и записывается в круглых скобках: `(x, y)`.

В Питоне элементы списка и элементы кортежи нумеруются от `0` - в примере списка кортежей

```
coordinates = [(1, 2), (7, 5), (-1, 3)]
```

- `coordinates[0]` будет `(1, 2)`
- `coordinates[1]` будет `(7, 5)`
- `coordinates[2]` будет `(-1, 3)`

  - `coordinates[2][0]` будет `-1`
  - `coordinates[2][1]` будет `3`

Comment: спасибо, большое

Comment: @allrighty1809, не стоит :-)

Answer (score 0):

Не создавайте *отдельные переменные* - например `x1`, `x2`, `x3` - а *список* для них, например

```
rectangles = []            # пустой список
```

и отдельные значения постепенно добавьте к нему:

```
rectangles.append(4)       # [4]
rectangles.append(7)       # [4, 7]
rectangles.append(9)       # [4, 7, 9]
```

Теперь `rectangles[0]` будет `4`, `rectangles[1]` будет `7` и `rectangles[2]` будет `9`.

Comment: @S.Nick, спасибо, исправил.

Comment: @S.Nick, ой, спасибо ещё раз, исправил.